# Updating the value of a variable not working ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have a list that should be updated when a post petition comes but it doesn't do anything, there aren't errors shown o something it just does not update can you spot the error or tell me a workaround of this?

Here's my code:

```
[ApiController]
public class UsersController : ControllerBase
{
    private List<User> users = new List<User>();

    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<User> getAllUsers() 
    {
        users.Add(new User(1,"alan","alavarez","vasquez",new Location("mexico","guanajuato"),"mail","1234"));
        users.Add(new User(1,"alan","alavarez","vasquez",new Location("mexico","guanajuato"),"mail","1234"));
        users.Add(new User(1,"alan","alavarez","vasquez",new Location("mexico","guanajuato"),"mail","1234"));
        return this.users;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IEnumerable<User> addNewUser(User user)
    {
        this.users.Add(user);
        return this.users;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The users field is instance and will be created and destroyed with your controller by every request. Mark users as static，make it a global variable，then you can add items to it by post。

```cs
private static List users = new List();
```

And search/replace all the `this.users` with `users` .

Comment: how do i make it global i'm sorry i'm new in this